# Best way to handle large json data backed with knockoutjs & MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, grid, scalability

We've a knockoutjs backed web dashboard. The server side is ASP.Net MVC3. Dashboard has a grid and a search panel. It needs to load fast so initially we load the page along with the search panel and basic grid.

Once the page is ready (loaded) in the $document.ready() we trigger a background ajax request to fetch json data. Then we use knockoutjs to bind data the grid. Things have been working fine but now data has grown over 8000+ records. So, it take a lot of time to load the 2+MB json data which keeps the user waiting.

> Some ideas like loading the json data in chunks and then use the
>   knockoutjs array.push method to append the dataset or refresh the
>   whole dataset, etc... but I can't keep the data as an observable array
>   (it costs a lot of size & performance).

**What are the best practices and ways to handle large json datasets with knockout js with tolerable delays?**

Also, we've our own custom native HTML rendered grid with some customization. The paging, sorting, etc.. are handled knockout *so better if the solution deals with the json dataset directly **instead of** some 3rd party grid plugins.* That would be a different path.

Thank you

Comment: What's the rational behind loading 8000 records on the client?

Comment: I'd agree with @RainerAtSpirit - Keep the data on the server until it's absolutely needed on the client.  Servers are much better at dealing with it than a web browser.

Comment: 8000 records. 2MB of json. I think it's time to implement some server side paging.

Comment: I understand and we're looking into the possibilities of reducing it but still with 50% less data also we want to be able to make the dashboard load faster! Also, if everything goes on server side the main goal of SPA withers !